# Move files in folders by pattern matching

Tags: regex, unix

I have some 250 files named:

```
xxxx_xx_S1_xx_L001_x.pdf
xxxx_xx_S2_xx_L002_x.pdf
xxxx_xx_S3_x_L002_xx.pdf
xxx_xx_S9_x_L002_xxxxx.pdf
```

and a list of folders named S1, S2, S3, S9

I would like to move the files in the corresponding folders according to S* 
that is a unique identifier.

I thought to something like this:

```
find . -name "*S*.pdf" | \
     while read filename
     do
     directory=${filename%.pdf}
     mv "$filename" "$directory"/"$filename"
     done
```

But unfortunately files are still there and folders empty.

Comment: Which shell are you using? do `echo $SHELL`

Comment: `rename '$_ = "$1/$_" if /_(S[^\W_]+)/' *.pdf`?